# Add fax number to exchage contanct using EWS API from FAX and Scan

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, contacts

I try Mictosoft [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ee693007(v=exchg.80))  to create and and contact to exchange server using EWS and strangly mark as invalid while try using fax number for sending using Windows Fax and Scan (wfs.exe).

So , Does anybody know how should I set fax number in EWS that can be usable for sending fax in fax and scan?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of exprementing and invaestigating using [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) I found out I should add a @ before number to be recognizable by Windows Fax and Scan. This is my final code.

```
public static ExchangeService GetService(string emailUser = defaultUser, string pass = defaultPass)
{

    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    //service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailUser, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
    service.Url = new Uri("https://xs3.domain.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(emailUser, pass);

    service.TraceEnabled = true;
    service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

    return service;
}

public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try
    {
        var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return addr.Address == email;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void AddOrUpdateContact(ExchangeService service, string id, Dictionary<string, string> dataRecord, string targetFolder = defaultCotactsFolder, bool faxOnly = false)
{

    Folder parentFolder;

    FindFoldersResults folderItems = service.FindFolders(
        WellKnownFolderName.Contacts,//parent folder
        new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, targetFolder),
        new FolderView(1)// return first 1 records
     );

    if (folderItems != null && folderItems.Count() > 0)
    {//folder found!
        parentFolder = folderItems.First() as Folder;
    }
    else
    {//folder NOT found!
        return;
    }

    ExtendedPropertyDefinition CustomProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "BusinessFax", MapiPropertyType.String);


    FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = service.FindItems(
        parentFolder.Id,
        new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactSchema.NickName, id),
        new ItemView(1)
    );

    bool doesExist = contactItems != null && contactItems.Count() > 0;
    Contact contact;


    if (doesExist)
    {//contact found!
        contact = contactItems.First() as Contact;
    }
    else
    {
        // Create the contact.
        contact = new Contact(service);
    }



    // Specify the name and how the contact should be filled.
    contact.CompanyName = name;
    contact.NickName = id;
    contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessFax] = "@"+dataRecord["COD_FAX_SUPID"];
    contact.FileAsMapping = FileAsMapping.Company;

    if (!faxOnly)
    {
        // Specify the business, home, and car phone numbers.
        contact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = dataRecord["COD_TEL_SUPID"];


        if (IsValidEmail(dataRecord["EMAIL_SUPID"]))
        {
            // Specify two email addresses.
            contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress(dataRecord["EMAIL_SUPID"]);
        }

        contact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] = new PhysicalAddressEntry()
        {
            Street = dataRecord["DES_STREET_SUPID"],
            City = dataRecord["DES_TOWN_SUPID"],
            CountryOrRegion = dataRecord["DES_COUNTRY_SUPID"],
            PostalCode = dataRecord["COD_POST_SUPID"] + (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataRecord["NUM_BOX_SUPID"]) ? "" : $", PostBox: {dataRecord["NUM_BOX_SUPID"]}"),
        }
    }


    if (doesExist)
    {  //contact found!
        contact.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
    }
    else
    {
        //save new!
        contact.Save(parentFolder.Id);
    }

}
```

Usage Example:

```
ExchangeService service = ContatctUpdaterLib.ContatcUpdater.GetService("USER@DONAMAIN.COM","123456");

//GetUserData return user data record as a Dictionary<string,string>
var data = GetUserData();

AddOrUpdateContact(service, dataRecord["COD_SUP_SUPID"], dataRecord, "Contacts(Fax Only)" ,true);
```